# Html table from json data without javascript

Tags: javascript, django-templates, tornado

I want to create an html table with json data, without using the js scripts I have seen in other questions here on stackoverflow.

I have this structure:

```
function visualize(json_response) {
  var err = json_response['error'];
  if (err) {
    $("#chart_div").html("<div class='alert'>" + err + "</div>");
    return;
  }
  var data = json_response['data'];
  if (data.length == 0) {

    {% elif net.ntype == "ztc" and sens.type == 2 %}
    $("#chart_div").html("<div class='info'>No data received from this contact sensor!</div>");

  }


  $("#chart_div").html('<img src="{{ static_url('img/loading.gif') }}">');

  {% if net.ntype == "ztc" and sens.type == 2 %}

  {% for d in data %} 
     $("#chart_div").append("<td>{% d %}<td>");
```

}

This is my js section. The html section, instead, is a simple div block:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
```

I want, in other words, put my data into a table. But this solution I've wrote is not working. I don't know I can do... any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's not JavaScript...

Comment: But the function is in a js script...

Comment: Yeah, I just mean what is all the `{% ... %}` stuff doing?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not so good. This is a tornado template.... i retrieve data from  tornado web server and put them in the data variable. Next, I want to create a table with this data that are {timestamp : value} .

Comment: OK, well the next thing to do is see what errors are displayed in the console. It looks to me as though you're trying to mix server-side and client-side code in one script!

Comment: Ok I have this error from Tornado:  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 826, in _parse
    raise ParseError("unknown operator: %r" % operator)
ParseError: unknown operator: 'd'

Comment: Ah... that's pretty gnarly. I have no idea - never used tornado templates before. Sorry!

Comment: No problem. Thank you! I hope someone will answer me! :)

Comment: am in windows, and normaly it's the same: in tornado template i've found a difference between {% if someting %} and { % if someting % } the second one will not work, there must not be a space between { or } and the percentage sign.

Comment: there is a tip, you can make a "dynamic" HTML, a tip is to use the "format" in python strings, just put r"<div>{0} other stuff {1}</div>".format(variable1, variable2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% %}` is for template directives, which must be one of the directives given in the [Tornado template syntax reference](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/template.html#syntax-reference).  `{{ }}` is for escaped output.

In the line:

```
     $("#chart_div").append("<td>{% d %}<td>");
```

`{% d %}` should be either `{{ d }}` (escaped) or `{% raw d %}` (unescaped). You also need to end the for loop.

Edit: I just looked at this again and it looks like you're trying to access a JavaScript variable in your Tornado template code (as Chris Francis pointed out). Template code (in the curly braces) is executed server-side; it has no access to or knowledge of JavaScript.

In this case, you can just use JQuery to iterate over the response:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
   $("#chart_div").append("<td>" + value + "<td>"); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah right! I've changed the statement and now I have this error: 

    `File "sensordata_html.generated.py", line 316, in _execute
    for d in data:  # sensordata.html:247 (via base.html:200)
    NameError: global name 'data' is not defined`

I have to change the fot loop? data is not defined in the html page? only in the js part? thank you!!!

Comment: because when you have {{}} it's a variable that you put there, and when you want a statement, you put in {% %}.
and you must pass the variable you want to put in {{}} in the self.render, for example self.render("miaw.html", cat="black cat") and in your template <h1>hi, am a {{cat}}</h1>

Comment: As Abdelouahab Pp said, the sections in the curly braces are python code. So, variables, like `data`, need to be defined. You can do this by passing them as keyword arguments to the RequestHandler render method.

Comment: and what if I write: `{% if net.ntype == "ztc" and sens.type == 2 %}

      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      $("#chart_div").append("<td>data[i]<td>");
      }`